# ZIP deflate percentage

Tags: bash, zip

using `zip archive file` I got:

```
adding: file (deflated 40%)

-rw-rw-r-- 1 lenduya lenduya 757 Jan 18 16:26 archive.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lenduya lenduya 973 Jan 18 16:25 file
```

The question is I'm not sure how it got the 40%. 973/757 is 1.28 and 757/973 is 0.77. 757/(973-757) is 3.5 and 973/(973/757) is 4.5.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Wrong question aside, I love that profile pic

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the zip file overhead. If I create an empty file and zip it, I get:

```
$ touch file
$ zip archive.zip file
  adding: file (stored 0%)

$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 dduponchel dduponchel 158 Jan 18 21:52 archive.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 dduponchel dduponchel   0 Jan 18 21:52 file
```

In this zip file, I have a local/central/end of central headers, metadata about this file, etc

You gained 40% by compressing your file (973 -> 583 bytes). Let's add 158 bytes of overhead (you may have a different value) and you have 741 bytes, near your 757 bytes.